# Can I configure Firefox "network request details" panel to always open below and not on the right?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I have by Firefox developer tools docked to the right. When I click on the individual network request from the network panel, it always opens on the right. And more often than not, the rest of the requests are unreadable (screenshot below)

[image: screenshot of network panel]

Now, when the width of the devtools panel is very low, it does move down. But I am wondering if I can configure it to always open below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, (as of Firefox 106) that is not possible. There are [two hardcoded thresholds](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/a3decf626dabd89620171f0ea7840cc4351fe218/devtools/client/netmonitor/src/components/MonitorPanel.js#52-58) when resizing the width of the DevTools that control whether the side panels are shown below the main panel or at the side.

This also applies to other panels [like the Inspector](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/a3decf626dabd89620171f0ea7840cc4351fe218/devtools/client/inspector/inspector.js#91-97).

Therefore, I have now [created a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1798564) to improve the UI on that.